# Firebase database when user try to register using onDataChange how to prevent from sending error toast

Tags: android, firebase

So when u try to register everything works great, when user register it show toast that user has successfully created and it also shows toast that username already exists. How can i prevent from showing toast that username already exists when user create his account, i guess it's the problem on onDataChange because it check always for that username is there any way i can do kinda better this, i'm new in android. Here is my register class.

```
btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(Common.isConnectedToInternet(getBaseContext())) {

table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //Check if already exist username
                        if(dataSnapshot.child(edtUsername.getText().toString()).exists()) {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            User user =
                              new User(edtUsername.getText().toString(),
                                      edtPassword.getText().toString());

                            table_user.child(edtUsername.getText().toString()).setValue(user);

                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Successfully Registration", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use addListenerForSingleValueEvent

```
mDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

     }
 });
```

so it should be like this

```
      btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(Common.isConnectedToInternet(getBaseContext())) {

table_user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //Check if already exist username
                        if(dataSnapshot.child(edtUsername.getText().toString()).exists()) {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            User user =
                              new User(edtUsername.getText().toString(),
                                      edtPassword.getText().toString());

                            table_user.child(edtUsername.getText().toString()).setValue(user);

                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Successfully Registration", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
```